# someone who knows anyone

Tags: some-vs-any

a. If you talk to someone who knows anyone, you'll find an answer to your question.

b. If you talk to someone who knows anyone in this office, you'll find an answer to your question.

Does 'anyone' mean 'at least one person, no matter who that person is' or does it mean 'everybody'?

Is there any ambiguity?

I think in order for it to have the second meaning, we'll need 'just anyone'.

I think in these sentences 'anyone' could be replaced with 'someone'.

Comment: Do you mean 'find **an** answer' ?

Comment: Where did you come across these sentences? What was the context? Or did you make them up? The meaning is not clear: "anyone" can mean "one or more persons" or (particularly in this kind of context) [it can mean](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anyone-who-is-anyone-anybody-who-is-anybody) "someone important".

Comment: Thank you Michael. I edited the question and corrected the typo. Stuart, the sentences are mine. I was trying to find out the differences between the meanings. ;Any' is a word that causes certain problems for me!

Comment: If you talk to anyone who knows someone in this office. etc. Surely that's the meaning.